# Changing pointer char value in function

Tags: c, pointers, char

I try to parse client HTML GET request and get address of file he wants to send. But when i pass argument to function  in path variable is bad output.
Parsers function printf: `New file path returned is=/somedir/index.html`
Main fuction printf: `In main path=random chars`

What is wrong?

```
int parser(char* buffer,char **newPath)
{
int numberOfChars = 0;
int index = 4;//start at 4 char

while(buffer[index] != ' '){
            numberOfChars++;
            index++;
}
// in numberOfChars is number of path characters from while loop
// this part of code is in if statment but it is irrelevant now
char filePath[numberOfChars];    
strncpy(filePath,buffer+4,numberOfChars);
char* fullPath;
fullPath = filePath;                
char name[] = "index.html";
strcat(fullPath,name);

(*newPath) = fullPath;
printf("New file path returned is=%s\n",(*newPath));
return 1;
//some more code if file is .sh or .bash or .png ...
.
.
}
```

main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
            //some code
            .
            .
            .
            char* path;
            //msg is client HTML get request i want parse it and send data
            // which he wants
            parser(msg,&path);
            printf("In main path=%s\n",path);
}
```

Comment: this line: `while(buffer[index] != ' '){` exits the loop when encountering a space, not when encountering the NUL byte at the end of the string.   Then this line: `char filePath[numberOfChars]; 1) does not allow room for trailing NUL char.  2) is too small to hold the buffer[5] through the end of the char array.  Then this line: `strncpy(filePath,buffer+4,numberOfChars);` filled up the flePath[] array (without including a NUL string termination char).  Then this line: `strcat(fullPath,name);` adds yet more characters, 'somewhere' beyond the end of the filePath[] array.  ==undefined behaviour

Comment: You are using `strncpy` incorrectly - check its manual to see why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char filePath[numberOfChars];    
char* fullPath;
fullPath = filePath; 
....
(*newPath) = fullPath;
```

`filePath` has automatic storage duration and you are accessing it after its lifetime is over. This is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead, you could use [`malloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and `strcpy()` to copy the string into `*newPath`.

Replace

```
(*newPath) = fullPath;
```

with:

```
*newPath = malloc(strlen(fullPath) + 1);
 if (*newPath == NULL) {
    /* handle error */
 }
strcpy(*newPath, fullPath);
```

and call [`free()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) in `main()` to de-allocate it.

---

As noted in the comments, you need to allocate one extra byte for the `'\0'` terminator. You can handle this by allocating an extra byte:

```
char filePath[numberOfChars + 1];    
strncpy(filePath,buffer+4,numberOfChars);
filePath[numberOfChars] = '\0';
```

`strncpy()` automatically fills rest of the with the memory with NUL bytes. In this case, just the last byte. In general, you don't want to use `strncpy()` as that would be unnecessary to fill the rest of the buffer with NUL bytes.

Comment: the filePath[] array has not been properly terminated, so the call to `strlen()` will fail to return the correct value.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks. I have updated to cover this. Hopefully, it's better now.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable.  When the function exits, that variable goes out of scope and the memory it occupied can be used for other purposes, leading to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Your function needs to dynamically allocate space for the string (and the NULL terminator) and return a pointer to that buffer.  You then need to be sure to `free` it in the calling function:

```
int parser(char* buffer,char **newPath) {
    ....
    char *filePath = malloc(numberOfChars+1);
    if (filePath == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    ...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    ...
    parser(msg,&path);
    printf("In main path=%s\n",path);
    free(path);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but @l3x was first.